# Typescript How to define generic method for Object, like object<T>

Tags: typescript

i want make generic functions for Object type in global.d.ts

because i want these function return type same as caller but there is some error

`global.d.ts`

```
declare global
{
    //declare extension methods for Array<T>
    interface Array<T>
    {
        addBy( item:any ): T[];
        GetRandom() : T;
        CloneItems() : T[];
        concatAll( items:T[] ) : T[]
    }
    
    // Error TS2428: All declarations of 'Object' must have identical type parameters.
    interface Object<T>
    {
        CloneFromLevelBy( str:Str ): T
    }
}
```

the `Array<T>` part is work,

how to make object part work?

thanks :>

### expect use case

In fact, below code is working in runtime, my main purpose is to make the code completion working in the `intelliJ idea`, and the typescript check not give me error

```
let obj:{ a:Int, b:Int } = { a:1, b:2 };

//this will clone only 'a' property
let cloned = obj.CloneFromLevelBy( 'a' ); 
    
let result = cloned.a; //Error: TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
```

The real CloneFromLevelBy function implement by Object.defineProperty to Object.prototype

```
Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, 'CloneFromLevelBy', 
{ value:
    function( levelDesc )
    {
        let clone = {};
        /* code... */
        return clone;
    }
})
```

Comment: What's your use case? Extending the `Object` prototype [is considered bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes). And [the `Object` definition in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L120-L150) is not generic, and so basic that the compiler won't even let you modify the existing library file locally. There *may* be workarounds, but I'd like to understand the use case.

Comment: You can't make `Object` generic, it is already defined once without generics, that is set in stone. You can make `CloneFromLevelBy` generic, maybe with a generic `this` parameter, but I would have to see a more coherent usage example before I could suggest something

Comment: add more information, thanks guys

Comment: So maybe you want `cloneFromLevelBy<T, K extends keyof T>(this: T, k: K): T[K]` (using a generic [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) as @TitianCernicova-Dragomir said) but can't you just use a standalone function rather than add `cloneFromLevelBy` into the prototype of every object everywhere?  I mean, are you designing this yourself or just trying to describe some prototype pollution being done already by some library you're using?  If it's the former, I'd suggest changing the design.

Comment: @jcalz this is my own method. It is intended to return only an object that only needs the required attributes, so that the following JSON.stringify can reduce the size of the message.

Comment: @jcalz thanks! the `CloneFromLevelBy<T>( this: T, k:Str | Str[] ): T` work! please post answer let me mark, thank you again :>